# Saving DOM Element into localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to save a variable that contains HTML Element, into localStorage, this way I can call that variable again (from localStorage) anytime I want.

I am executing the javascript in the background & content script of chrome extension

So I create the variable and load it with the HTML Element that I want to save:

```
var btnelm = document.getElementById("ELM_ID");
```

I then attempt to save that variable into localStorage (hoping to be able to use that variable later)

```
localStorage["btnelm"] = btnelm;
```

But when I called the localStorage which I need it to contain the html element in my variable

```
localStorage["btnelm"]
```

I get this string text (and not the actual html element that was in my `btnelm` variable:

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Which of course means, when I treat `localStorage["btnelm"]` as a variable containing my html element, it does not work:

`localStorage["btnelm"].innerHTML` returns `undefined`

I understand that localStorage stores only `string` values, so what are my options to be able to store my
`btnelm` and when called, be able to treat it as when I first created (i.e. accessing it with `.childern` for example)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't store DOM elements in storage. You can store `btnelm.innerHTML` there.

Comment: @wOxxOm so that scenario I am trying to achieve is not possible? even using any other method beside the localStorage

Comment: Why would you not just query the DOM again next time you need it? You can just put it in a variable and access that until the page refreshes and then get it again when that goes out of scope. You shouldn't be dealing with the DOM outside of UI context.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save the DOM element itself... But you can save its [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

```
<div id="ELM_ID">My Div</div>

var btnelm = document.getElementById("ELM_ID").outerHTML;  // <== here

localStorage["btnelm"] = btnelm;
console.log(localStorage["btnelm"]);
```

The outputs is :

```
"<div id='ELM_ID'>My Div</div>"
```

---

**EDIT**

To use the outerHTML once retreived... And look for its properties as is was a real DOM element, simply use the `.createElement()` method to *"recreate"* it...

```
let tempElement = document.createElement("div")
tempElement.innerHTML = localStorage["btnelm"]
console.log(tempElement.children[0].innerText) // Will output "My Div"
```

Comment: That will only save the outerHTML text into the localStorage, and when localStorage["btnelm"].innerText is called, it will return `undefined` which is not what I want